# Has ASP.NET Identity UserManager.CreateAsync() been updated with breaking changes recently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, dapper

A few months ago I created my own implementation of ASP.NET Identity, overriding the UserStore to use dapper and a custom sql connection instead of Entity Framework. It worked fine at the time.

Now I updated all of the nuget packages today and I've been fighting problems since. Primarily when I register a new user by calling  `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, newAccount.Password);` It creates the user and performs all other checks just fine, but then throws a bizarre error saying `Invalid operation. The connection is closed.`

Its as though UserManager.CreateAsync has a new method that needs to be overridden, but I have absolutely no idea what it could be.

For reference, here are parts of my implementation:

**Account Controller:**

```
        [Authorize]
            public class AccountController : Controller
            {

                public UserManager<User> UserManager { get; private set; }
                public UserTokenProvider UserTokenProvider { get; set; }

                public AccountController() : this(new UserManager<User>(new UserStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString)))
                {
                }

                public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
                {
                    UserManager = userManager;
                    UserManager.PasswordHasher = new NoPasswordHasher();

                }

...

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegistrationModel newAccount)
        {
            try
            {
                if (DbConfig.MaintenanceMode) return RedirectToAction("ComingSoon", "Home");
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = new User(newAccount);

                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, newAccount.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        var userIn = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(newAccount.UserName);
                        if (!userIn.EmailConfirmed)
                        {
                            await SendValidationEmail(userIn);
                            return RedirectToAction("ConfirmationSent", new {userName = user.UserName});
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }

                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                return View(newAccount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;

                return View(newAccount);
            }
        }
```

**User Store:**

```
    public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserLoginStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>, IUserSecurityStampStore<User>, IUserRoleStore<User>, IUserEmailStore<User>
        {
            private readonly string _dbConn;


            public UserStore(string conn = null)
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    _dbConn = conn;
                else
                    _dbConn = DbConfig.ConnectionString;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }



            public virtual Task CreateAsync(User user)
            {
                using (var _conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConn))
                {
                    if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _conn.Open();
                    return _conn.ExecuteAsync("users_UserCreate",
                        new
                        {
                            @UserId = user.Id,
                            @UserName = user.UserName,
                            @PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash,
                            @SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp
                        }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                }
            }

... Remaining methods omitted for brevity ...
```

You'll notice that the UserStore.CreateAsync() function has `if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _conn.Open();` as this was the suggestion from multiple threads regarding the connection closed error. Even without this line the query works fine and inserts a new user into the database correctly.

The error is coming from somewhere after UserStore.CreateAsync() is called by UserManager.CreateAsync().

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, ASP.NET Identity hasn't altered with breaking changes.

Using DotNetPeek I had a look at the Identity library to see what methods were being called during UserManager.CreateAsync() and it only calls UserStore.CreateSync and a password update.

After playing around with the code some more it dawned on me that whilst UserManager.CreateSync is awaited, the internal calls to UserStore.CreateSync isn't. Tanks to having to override `public virtual Task CreateAsync(User user)` and having to return a task that isn't awaited, we have to juggle some code to await the response from Dapper before returning it as part of a task again.

So, here's the updated UserStore.CreateAsync override that works. Note: `if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _conn.Open();` isn't actually needed as the connection was being closed before the method had finished, Dapper does a brilliant job of handling connections for you.

```
public virtual Task CreateAsync(User user)
{
    using (var _conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConn))
    {
        var result = _conn.ExecuteAsync("users_UserCreate", new
                    {
                        @UserId = user.Id,
                        @UserName = user.UserName,
                        @PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash,
                        @SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp
                    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(true);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future facing the same sort of problem.

Comment: On netcore 2.1.302, if we do not wait CreateAsync execution, it throws an exception in both Azure and local SqlServer. In this case, it is a Seed clas which has `await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);` within a for loop. I tried do add roles with DataContext and noticed: async only saves 1st role in a list (weird); without async works fine and all roles are saved in AspNetRoles table. Another way to make CreateAsync work with SqlServer is editing Startup.cs and Wait() seed execution `mySeeder.SeedUsers().Wait();`. SeedUsers here is a custom method which runs CreateAsync for roles and users.